UserManager.GetClaimsAsync() failing - The connection is closed
In a Blazor InteractiveServer application, using the ASP.NET Identity Library, I call:
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1.GetClaimsAsync(TUser user)
I set it to use my extension class by adding it in Program.cs
builder.Services.AddScoped<AuthenticationStateProvider, ExAuthenticationStateProvider>();

Other than adding that line, all of the use of this is the Blazor stack calling this when it chooses to. The only time I directly call anything in this class is when I call ResetNextCheck().
And it throws (full stack trace below).
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query - An exception occurred while iterating over the results of a query for context type 'LouisHowe.web.Areas.Identity.Data.UserDbContext'.
System.InvalidOperationException: Invalid operation. The connection is closed.

The claims table has 34 entries so reading the entire table, if requested (it isn't) is fast.
The one non-standard part of all this in my app is I have class ExIdentityUser : IdentityUser where I add a public bool Enabled { get; set; }. And so my DbContext is UserDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ExIdentityUser>.
This is occurring inside my ExAuthenticationStateProvider : ServerAuthenticationStateProvider GetAuthenticationStateAsync() method.
Why is this closing the connection in this call?
Full log:
Error 08:52:21 [] Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command - Failed executing DbCommand (19ms) [Parameters=[@__user_Id_0='?' (Size = 450)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
SELECT [a].[Id], [a].[ClaimType], [a].[ClaimValue], [a].[UserId]
FROM [AspNetUserClaims] AS [a]
WHERE [a].[UserId] = @__user_Id_0

// 20 irrelevant log messages

Error 08:52:22 [] Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query - An exception occurred while iterating over the results of a query for context type 'LouisHowe.web.Areas.Identity.Data.UserDbContext'.
System.InvalidOperationException: Invalid operation. The connection is closed.
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationResultTaskFromResultTask`2.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(Task& currentTaskSlot, Thread threadPoolThread)
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.InitializeReaderAsync(AsyncEnumerator enumerator, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.ExecuteAsync[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`4 operation, Func`4 verifySucceeded, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.MoveNextAsync() InvalidOperationException: Invalid operation. The connection is closed.
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationResultTaskFromResultTask`2.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(Task& currentTaskSlot, Thread threadPoolThread)
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.InitializeReaderAsync(AsyncEnumerator enumerator, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.ExecuteAsync[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`4 operation, Func`4 verifySucceeded, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.MoveNextAsync()
Error 08:52:22 [] LouisHowe.web.Services.ExAuthenticationStateProvider - GetAuthenticationStateAsync() exception: Invalid operation. The connection is closed. InvalidOperationException: Invalid operation. The connection is closed.
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationResultTaskFromResultTask`2.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(Task& currentTaskSlot, Thread threadPoolThread)
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.InitializeReaderAsync(AsyncEnumerator enumerator, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.ExecuteAsync[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`4 operation, Func`4 verifySucceeded, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.MoveNextAsync()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.ToListAsync[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.ToListAsync[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.UserOnlyStore`6.GetClaimsAsync(TUser user, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1.GetClaimsAsync(TUser user)
   at LouisHowe.web.Services.ExAuthenticationStateProvider.GetAuthenticationStateAsync() in D:\a\LouisHowe\LouisHowe\LouisHowe.web\Services\ExAuthenticationStateProvider.cs:line 94


Are other queries resulting in the same error? Is the app still running fine after receiving this error? Can you show the exact code that you have to get the claims via user manager?

@HenkHolterman I added how it's injected, etc. All I do is an AddScoped() call in Program.cs. When it's called, awaited, etc. is Blazor and/or the Identity Library. I also found a fix (added below), but I have no idea why this fixes it - which always worries me. thanks

I fixed it (explanation below). With that said, I don't know why this fixes it.
I was using UserManager<ExIdentityUser> to call:
userManager.FindByIdAsync(id);
userManager.GetClaimsAsync(user);

Those call were occasionally failing because the underlying DbConnection was closed. I have no idea why, especially as sometimes the call to FindByIdAsync() would succeed, then the immediately following call to GetClaimsAsync() would have a closed connection.
To work around this I changed it to use:
IDbContextFactory<UserDbContext> UserDbFactory;
var dbContext = await UserDbFactory.CreateDbContextAsync();
var user = await dbContext.Users.Where(u => u.Id == id).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
var list = await dbContext.UserClaims.Where(uc => uc.UserId == id).ToListAsync();

That not only resolved my issue with the DbConnection sometimes being closed, it also resolved this issue. As I said above, no idea why. But calling the UserManager methods did something to set NotifyAuthenticationStateChanged() to fail. Switching to UserDbFactory fixed this issue as well as the other issue.
